# In a List, get "team" from a player in "all_players" without the "name"

Tags: python

my question is about this list that i have. In the list are 2 things: "meta-data" and "players" in "players" is "all_players". Now i want to get the Player Name and Player Team but i dont know how i can do this. i can do `data["data"][i]['players']['all_players'][{name}]` but then i only have the name, and i cant get the team when i dont know which player the team i should get.

Here is my List:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "metadata": {
                "map": "Breeze",
                "game_length": 1702289,
                "game_start": 1657464507,
                "game_start_patched": "Sunday, July 10, 2022 4:48 PM",
                "rounds_played": 20,
                "mode": "Competitive",
                "queue": "Standard",
                "platform": "PC",
                "region": "eu",
                "cluster": "London"
            },
            "players": {
                "all_players": [
                    {
                        "puuid": "70f7373a-ba78-5c9a-a963-767fbf27d9ad",
                        "name": "Player 1",
                        "team": "Blue"
                    },
                    {
                        "puuid": "70f7373a-ba78-5c9a-a963-767fbf27d9ad",
                        "name": "Player 2",
                        "team": "Blue"
                    },
                    {
                        "puuid": "70f7373a-ba78-5c9a-a963-767fbf27d9ad",
                        "name": "Player 3",
                        "team": "Red"
                    },
                ]}
        }]
}
```

This is only a small part, where things are what i want to have. The List is way longer but its unnecessary for this part This List or Data is from a JSON.

Comment: Do you want to get the player's team by player name?

Comment: too! i want to get it without name and the name, just for the tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do what your question asks:

```py
all_players = data["data"][0]["players"]["all_players"]
playerNames = [player["name"] for player in all_players]
teamNames = [player["team"] for player in all_players]
teamByPlayer = {player["name"]:player["team"] for player in all_players}
```

Output

```
playerNames
['Player 1', 'Player 2', 'Player 3']

teamNames
['Blue', 'Blue', 'Red']

teamByPlayer
{'Player 1': 'Blue', 'Player 2': 'Blue', 'Player 3': 'Red'}
```

Explanation:

- The assignments for `playerNames` and `teamNames` each use a [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to create a list based on the items in the `for` loop.
- The assignment for `teamNames` uses a [`dict comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to add a key:value pair using key `player["name"]` and value `player["team"]` for each `player` in the `for` loop.

To find the team for a given player, you can do this using [`accumulate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```py
from itertools import accumulate
def findTeamOfPlayer(player):
    all_players = data["data"][0]["players"]["all_players"]
    team = list(accumulate(p["team"] for p in all_players if p["name"] == player))
    return team[0] if team else None

target = "Player 2"
team = findTeamOfPlayer("Player 2")
print(team)
team = findTeamOfPlayer("Player 99")
print(team)
```

Output:

```
Blue
None
```

Comment: Thanks! question: what does this : mean between player["name"] and player["team"]

Comment: In a dict comprehension (explained under [Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) in the docs), they give the example `{x: x**2 for x in (2, 4, 6)}` where `x` is the key and `x**2` is the value, with all key/value pairs `x: x**2` in the `for` loop to be added to the dictionary. So in our case, `player["name"]:player["team"] for player in all_players}` is a `dict comprehension` that creates a dictionary with `player["name"]` as key and `player["team"]` as value for every `player` in `all_players`.

Comment: Okay! And what if, i dont want all players their teams but only one player? Like i only want the Team of Player 2?

Comment: See my updated answer for one example of how to find the team for a given player name.